Does $\mathbb{E}[X|X^2]=0$ imply that the distribution of $X$ is symmetric?
I have already known that it is true in the cases where $X$(a real random variable) admits a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure and where $X$ takes countable values because in both cases we can give concrete formulas of $\mathbb{E}[X|X^2]$.
But I wonder if it is possible to prove the proposition in the general case.
Thanks!

Note that $E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|\leq n\}}X^{2k+1}]=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|\leq n\}}X^{2k}E[X|X^2]]=0$ for any $n,k\in\mathbb{N}_0$. So if $f$ is a polynomial, $E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|\leq n\}}f(X)]=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|-X|\leq n\}}f(-X)]$. It follows by Stone-Weierstrass that for any continuous bounded function $u$ we have $E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X|\leq n\}}u(X)]=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|-X|\leq n\}}u(-X)]$. By dominated convergence, $E[u(X)]=E[u(-X)]$. We conclude that $P_X=P_{-X}$.

Thanks! This concise argument with Stone-Weierstrass is impressive!

You are welcome @Florian!

Define
$$
h(u):=1-{u\over 3!}+{u^2\over 4!}-+\cdots =\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n {u^n\over (2n+1)!},\qquad u\in\Bbb R.
$$
The series converges absolutely, and uniformly on bounded intervals. You have
$$
\sin(x)=xh(x^2)
$$
for all real $x$. In particular,
$$
\sin(tX)=tXh(t^2X^2)
$$
for all real $t$, so
$$
\Bbb E[\sin(tX)] =\Bbb E[tXh(t^2X^2)]=t\Bbb E[h(t^2X^2)\Bbb E[X\,|\, X^2]]=0,
$$
for all real $t$. Consequently
$$
\Bbb E[e^{itX}]-\Bbb E[e^{-itX}] =2i\Bbb E[\sin(tX)]=0,
$$
for all real $t$. That is, $X$ and $-X$ have the same characteristic function, hence the same distribution.

It is true in the general case.
There exists a measurable map $p:\mathbb R_+\to[0,1]$ such that $\mathbb E[1_{\{X\ge0\}}\vert X^2]=p(X^2)$. Then $\mathbb E[1_{\{X<0\}}\vert X^2]=1-p(X^2)$, and
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\vert X^2]&=\mathbb E[\sqrt{X^2}1_{\{X\ge0\}}\vert X^2]+\mathbb E[-\sqrt{X^2}1_{\{X<0\}}\vert X^2]\\
&=\sqrt{X^2}p(X^2)-\sqrt{X^2}(1-p(X^2))\\
&=\sqrt{X^2}(2p(X^2)-1).
\end{align}
$$
By assumption, $\mathbb E[X\vert X^2]=0$ a.s., which means that $2p(X^2)-1=0$ a.s. on the set $\{\sqrt{X^2}\neq0\}$. In other words,
$$
p(X^2)1_{\{X\neq0\}}=\frac121_{\{X\neq0\}}.
$$
Now let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and continuous. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[f(X)]&=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[f(X)\vert X^2]]\\
&=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[f(\sqrt{X^2})1_{\{X\ge0\}}\vert X^2]+\mathbb E[f(-\sqrt{X^2})1_{\{X<0\}}\vert X^2]]\\
&=\mathbb E[f(\sqrt{X^2})p(X^2)+f(-\sqrt{X^2})(1-p(X^2))]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[1_{\{X\neq0\}}\left(f(\sqrt{X^2})p(X^2)+f(-\sqrt{X^2})(1-p(X^2))\right)+1_{\{X=0\}}f(0)\right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[1_{\{X\neq0\}}\frac{f(\sqrt{X^2})+f(-\sqrt{X^2})}{2}+1_{\{X=0\}}f(0)\right].
\end{align}
$$
Let $g:x\mapsto f(-x)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[f(-X)]&=\mathbb E[g(X)]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[1_{\{X\neq0\}}\frac{g(\sqrt{X^2})+g(-\sqrt{X^2})}{2}+1_{\{X=0\}}g(0)\right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[1_{\{X\neq0\}}\frac{f(-\sqrt{X^2})+f(\sqrt{X^2})}{2}+1_{\{X=0\}}f(0)\right]\\
&=\mathbb E[f(X)],
\end{align}
$$
hence the distribution of $X$ is symmetric.

Thanks for this detailed answer!
